Flutter Nisted Listview builder with lazyload for each one
enter image description hereIn my case, there is a ListView builder for the Group header, and for each Group, there is a ListView builder for the items of the Group. Both the internal and external lists use lazy loading. What is the best solution for this?
the issue in this code is when the inner list ends the outter not scrolling
what I need is to start scrolling the out when the inner ends
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GroupedLazyLoadList(),
    );
  }
}

class Group {
  final int id;
  final List<int> items;
  bool isLoading;

  Group(this.id, this.items, {this.isLoading = false});
}

class GroupedLazyLoadList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GroupedLazyLoadListState createState() => _GroupedLazyLoadListState();
}

class _GroupedLazyLoadListState extends State<GroupedLazyLoadList> {
  final List<Group> _groups = List.generate(5, (index) => Group(index, List.generate(5, (itemIndex) => itemIndex)));
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _loadMoreGroups();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _loadMoreGroups() async {
    if (_groups.isNotEmpty && _groups.last.isLoading) return;
    setState(() {
      if (_groups.isNotEmpty) _groups.last.isLoading = true;
    });

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // Simulate network delay

    setState(() {
      if (_groups.isNotEmpty) _groups.last.isLoading = false;
      _groups.add(Group(_groups.length, List.generate(5, (itemIndex) => itemIndex)));
    });
  }

  Future<void> _loadMoreItems(Group group) async {
    if (group.isLoading) return;
    setState(() {
      group.isLoading = true;
    });

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // Simulate network delay

    setState(() {
      group.isLoading = false;
      group.items.addAll(List.generate(5, (itemIndex) => group.items.length + itemIndex));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Grouped Lazy Load List'),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int groupIndex) {
                if (groupIndex == _groups.length) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                Group group = _groups[groupIndex];
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text('Group ${group.id}'),
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: group.items.length + (group.isLoading ? 1 : 0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, itemIndex) {
                        if (itemIndex == group.items.length) {
                          return Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          );
                        }
                        if (itemIndex == group.items.length - 1) {
                          // Check if we need to load more items for this group
                          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            _loadMoreItems(group);
                          });
                        }
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text('Item ${group.items[itemIndex]}'),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
              childCount: _groups.length + 1,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


